# activeMQ master/slave SASL configuration

Tags: activemq-classic, sasl

I have 2 servers running activeMQ, one is master,  the other is slave,  via  zookeeper.

I run the following:

```
Downloads\apache-activemq-5.9.1-bin\apache-activemq-5.9.1\bin\win64>activemq.bat
```

some WARN here:

```
jvm 1    |  WARN | SASL configuration failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No JAAS configuration section named 'Client' was found in specified JAAS configuration file: '../../conf/login.config'. Will continue connection to Zookeeper server without SASL authentication, if Zookeeper server allows it.
jvm 1    |  INFO | Opening socket connection to server "server1"
jvm 1    |  WARN | unprocessed event state: AuthFailed
jvm 1    |  INFO | Socket connection established to blabla.local/10.112.0.17:2181, initiating session
jvm 1    |  INFO | Session establishment complete on server blabla.local/10.112.0.17:2181, sessionid = 0x14651b3478a0005, negotiated timeout = 4000
```

My '../../conf/login.config'  looks like :

```
activemq {
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="users.properties"
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.group="groups.properties";
};
```

My "username" and "password" are configured in '../../conf/activemq.xml' via "simpleAuthenticationPlugin ",  not in '../../conf/login.config'

anyone knows about the WARNING i have above?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Make `zookeeper` client version the same with `zookeeper` server version:

```
zookeeper client jar location:
[ActiveMQ]/lib/optional/zookeeper.jar
```